# Find all MKV, extract English subtitles, remove all subtitles, delete original MKV from subtitles removed

Tags: windows, batch-file, extract, subtitles, matroska

[So far](https://superuser.com/questions/599405/find-all-mkv-files-and-remove-all-subtitles):

```
@echo off
cls
set rootfolder=C:\
echo Enumerating all MKVs under %rootfolder%
echo.
for /r %rootfolder% %%a in (*.mkv) do (
    for /f %%b in ('mkvmerge --identify-verbose "%%a" ^| find /c /i "subtitles"') do (
        if [%%b]==[0] (
            echo "%%a" has no subtitles
        ) else (
            echo.
            echo "%%a" has subtitles
            mkvmerge -q -o "%%~dpna (No Subs)%%~xa" -S "%%a"
            if errorlevel 1 (
                echo Warnings/errors generated during remuxing, original file not deleted
            ) else (
                del /f "%%a"
                echo Successfully remuxed to "%%~dpna (No Subs)%%~xa", original file deleted
            )
            echo.
        )
    )
)
```

Which finds all MKV files recursively from a specified path, and removes all subtitles from the MKV files found (if the MKV found contains subtitles), finally deleting all the original MKV files that had the subtitles removed.

I'm looking to add when it runs `mkvmerge -i` if has English subtitles, tell it to extract them to the directory of the MKV file before remuxing (using [mkvextract](http://www.bunkus.org/videotools/mkvtoolnix/doc/mkvextract.html)).

Comment: Does `mkvmerge -i` show the language of the subs?

Comment: No, looks like I'm asking the wrong question.

Comment: It shoes the language with the `mkvmerge --identify-verbose`  switch.

Comment: IT DOES!! Yay were getting somewhere!!!

Comment: Edited the batch file to include --identify-verbose above.

Comment: The issue is, `mkvmerge --identify-verbose` makes strings with lenghts over 13,000 chars, look [here](http://pastebin.com/Y84tmpi7), this is more for and [findstr](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8844873/2098699) can treat. Therefore I would suggest to use [sed](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm) in the batch script.

Comment: And, moreover, there is a nice GUI for batch demuxing, [mkvcleaver](http://apps.einsof-haras.ca/).

Comment: I have SAB***d run a batch script that has 4 other batch scripts. I'm not looking to use a GUI manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Identify english subtitles in MKV video files with [GNU sed](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm):

```
@echo off&setlocal
set "rootfolder=C:\video\test"
echo Enumerating all MKVs under %rootfolder%
echo.
for /r "%rootfolder%" %%a in (*.mkv) do (
    for /f %%b in ('mkvmerge  --ui-language en -i "%%a" ^| find /c /i "subtitles"') do (
        if "%%b"=="0" (
            echo(%%a has no subtitles
        ) else (
            echo(%%a has subtitles
            set "line="
            for /f "delims=" %%i in ('mkvmerge --ui-language en --identify-verbose "%%a" ^| sed "/subtitles/!d;/language:eng/!d;s/.* \([0-9]*\):.*/\1/"') do (
                echo(english Track ID: %%i
                call set line=%%line%% %%i:"%%~dpna (Sub Track %%i).sub"
            )
            setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
            mkvextract tracks "%%a" --ui-language en !line! ||(echo Demuxing error!&goto:eof)
            endlocal
            mkvmerge -q -o "%%~dpna (No Subs)%%~xa" -S "%%a"
            if errorlevel 1 (
                echo Warnings/errors generated during remuxing, original file not deleted
            ) else (
                del /f "%%a"
                echo Successfully remuxed to "%%~dpna (No Subs)%%~xa", original file deleted
            )
            echo(
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: I installed sed-src. Can't find app to add to me environment variables.

Comment: Press `[Windows]+[Pause]`, select --> `Advanced` --> `Environment Variables`

Comment: @Endoro: Unfortunately this is heavily dependent on the proper language code being specified in the MKV for each track. For example, I have a bunch of files [like this](http://pastebin.com/DwXKsYvb) where this will obviously fail, although *both* embedded subtitle tracks are in English. I don't know if there's a better solution though; will have to look into this a bit more when I have some free time on my hands.

Comment: OOps. I'm sorry I wasn't clear. I cannot find sed.exe I looking in all the program files for sed and cannot find any application.

Comment: I installed sed fine. But all I see is a Makefile

Comment: No I did the complete package with src.

Comment: @Karan - my code does find **all** english subs, even "multiple". Look at the code .....

Comment: Just downloaded the binary, and it has the exe, I guess I'll just uninstall the complete package.

Comment: @David do you want to compile your own sed, or do you want to **use** sed??

Comment: I'd like to just use SED. Thats why I used the complete package. I must be really dumb. sorry. The Binary is missing .dll. Only exe in folder for binary. What is the easiest way to use sed?

Comment: @Endoro: You're right, that %%i in the for loop will be set to multiple track IDs if required. I was thinking of how I do it manually, which is to specify all tracks to be extracted in one go, i.e. `1:subtrack1.sub 2:subtrack2.sub` etc. Here mkvextract will be executed multiple times, once per subtitle track.

Comment: @Karan - if you are in a hurry and have no time for demuxing you can build just **one** command line for mkvextract. This more demuxing takes me only a few extra seconds ...

Comment: @Endoro: It's fine, I was just commenting on how the code works vs. how I do it manually. I don't think running mkvextract multiple times will cause a significant delay, even with large files. If required I guess a single pass can be achieved with more code, but why bother? It's not like a few seconds saved per file is going to make such a huge difference here.

Comment: So what do I do about this sed? When I install using the complete package, i get a makefile. When I download binary, I get a exe but no dll.

Comment: I installed the exe they give you. From there I got a makefile.

Comment: Download sed-4.2.1-setup.exe  [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuwin32/files//sed/4.2.1/sed-4.2.1-setup.exe/download)

Comment: I should have done that in the first place. I just didn't know If I'd need to source at any point. Obviously that was a STupid notion.

Comment: OMFG it works. You sir are my HERO!

Comment: @David - I changed my code to have ONLY one call of MKVExtract. You can try this too.