# Windows - Is it possible with MKV Merge to remove all subtitles that do not match given name

Tags: windows-10, matroska

I found this code:

```
:: remux all mkvs under a certain subfolder with all subitles
:: but those as specified by %language% parameter removed.

@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:: set your variables here
set rootfolder="C:\temp\New folder"
set language=eng
set suffix= (eng sub)

:: do the remuxing
echo Remuxing all mkvs in %rootfolder% and its subfolders.
for /r %rootfolder% %%a in (*.mkv) do (
    set subs=
    set mkv=%%a
    for /f "tokens=3 delims=: " %%b in ('mkvmerge -I "%%a" ^| findstr /i /r 
".*subtitles.*language:%language%.*"') do (
        set subs=!subs!,%%b
    )
    for /f "tokens=*delims=," %%c in ("!subs!") do (
        set subs=%%c
    )
    if not exist "%%~dpna%suffix%%%~xa" if not "!subs!"=="" (
        mkvmerge -q -o "%%~dpna%suffix%%%~xa" -s !subs! "%%a"
        if errorlevel 1 (
            echo Warnings/errors generated during remuxing of "%%a".
        ) else (
            echo Successfully remuxed to "%%~dpna (eng subs)%%~xa".
        )
    ) else (
        echo Input file "%%a" has no subtitles in %language% or output file 
"%%~dpna%suffix%%%~xa" already exists. Skipping this file.
    )
)
pause
```

is it possible to rework this code to take a subtitle name in stead of language?
found the code here: https://superuser.com/a/762617/1089631